# Replace text in XML node containg ampersand

Tags: powershell, replace, contains, selectnodes

I have a PowerShell script in which it is trying to replace the values in an XML file node with a different value.

Example, within the `SectorDesc` node replace '&' with 'and'.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OrganisationUnits>
  <OrganisationUnitsRow num="8">
    <OrganisationId>ACME24/7HOME</OrganisationId>
    <OrganisationName>ACME LTD</OrganisationName>
    <ContactDetails>
      <ContactDetailsRow num="1">
        <ContactCode>OFFICE</ContactCode>
      </ContactDetailsRow>
    </ContactDetails>
    <Sector>P</Sector>
    <SectorDesc>Private Private &amp; Voluntary</SectorDesc>
  </OrganisationUnitsRow>
</OrganisationUnits>
```

So this line

```
<SectorDesc>Private Private &amp; Voluntary</SectorDesc>
```

woudl now look like this

```
<SectorDesc>Private Private and Voluntary</SectorDesc>
```

This is my code so far.

```
$file = "C:\Dump\test\test.xml"
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $file)
$xml.selectNodes('//SectorDesc/value[contains(.,"text")]')|
                ForEach-Object{$_.'#text' = ($_.'#text' -replace "&amp;","and") } 

$xml.Save("$File")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the xml like this `&amp;` will get read as just `&` so you have to replace for `&`. Also, you can access the node like this:

```
$xml.OrganisationUnits.OrganisationUnitsRow.SectorDesc = $xml.OrganisationUnits.OrganisationUnitsRow.SectorDesc -replace '&', 'and'
```

Comment: The reason why I want to replace &amp; with another character is because the application that will be importing the XML cannot handle it. I know that it is valid xml but the app wont take it, hence why some transform work is required.
I have tried the code as suggested but when &amp; is used it does nor perform the replace.

Comment: Just use the Code i provided with &